# If $A\ast_C B$ is finitely generated, are $A$ and $B$ finitely generated?

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, combinatorial-group-theory, free-product

<s>I know that if $A$ and $B$ are group of finite rank $n$, there is an amalgamated product $A\ast_{F_2} B$ of rank $2$</s>. It is know that for every $n$ there exist groups $A$ and $B$ of rank $\ge n$ and suitable injective group morphisms $F_2 \to A$ and $F_2 \to B$ from the free group on two generators such that the amalgamated product $A \ast_{F_2} B$ has rank $2$. So amalgamated products do not behave well with respect to (minimal) cardinality of generators.

But how terrible can it be? Can we find, for instance, non finitely generated $A$ and $B$ (or: at least one of the two is not finitely generated) with $A\ast_C B$ finitely generated? What about the same question for finitely presented groups?

Edit: to be more concrete, I hope that the following is true, but I suspect it is not: if $A \ast_C B$ is finitely presented, then both $A$ and $B$ are finitely generated.

Comment: No, if $A, B$ are of rank $\le n$, then the amalgam, in general, is not of rank $2$, it is of rank $\le 2n$. In your question about $A*_C B$, are you assuming that $C$ is finitely generated (or finitely presented)?

Comment: @MoisheKohan See here: https://www.math.uni-kiel.de/algebra/de/weidmann/research/material-research/grushko-finite-pdf . In the case of interest $C$ can be arbitrary, but if you know results under some assumptions on $C$, those are also welcome.

Comment: Weidemann surely simply made a typo and he meant $2n$. If you make no assumptions on $C$ then finite generation will fail even if $A*C_B$ is a free group of finite rank.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Weidemann makes reference to this: https://www.math.uni-kiel.de/algebra/de/weidmann/research/material-research/nielsen-pdf . This is dealt with in section 3.2 and the rank is $2$. I have not read the proof, so I do not want to insist, but it seems it is not a typo, at least.

Comment: There are trivial counterexamples if you don't require the free product to be nondegenerate. E.g., take $A=F_2$, $B=C=[A,A]$. Then $A*_CB = A$ is finitely generated, by $B$ is not.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you, also, I have added an edit.

Comment: That edit does not get rid of the example above. $A*_CB$ is finitely presented, but $B$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: The claim about rank 2 is plain false. As an example, take $A=F_m*F_2$, $B=F_m*F_2$, $C=F_2$ the common  factor in both. The amalgam is isomorphic to $F_{2m+2}$ which has rank $2m+2$. I do not know what Weidemann was thinking.

Comment: @MoisheKohan He claims that there exist groups $A$ and $B$ with that property, not that for every choice of $A$ and $B$ of rank $\ge n$ and every choice of monomorphisms $F_2 \to A, B$ you have that the rank of $A \ast_{F_2} B$ is $2$, which would be false, of course. I realize that as I have written it, it is false, but still, I haven't written that every amalgamated product has such property. Sorry for the confusion.